# Amazon product advertising API alternative

Tags: database, api, data, scraping, amazon

Because my website is not online yet i could not use amazon products API in it, so I'm looking for an alternative that would let me do that.
so can you recommend any good free alternative to Amazon product advertising API?

Like another API or something like that!

**requirements:**

- free
- Supports python
- has stuff like the price of the product,technical details about the product (if it's a PC or a phone or..) etc..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community is it clear now?

Comment: Community is a bot, so it won't answer :) But no, not entirely. What features do you need? What programming language(s) must be supported?

Comment: @Izzy ok i'll specify that